# mySQL size of table when joined

Tags: php, mysql

My website has a phone chat system with a large number with visitors ( 4000 msg/day )

I have 3 channels. I created a table for each of the category's

table chat 63690 rows 8,5 MB

table date 67602 rows 9.5 MB

table gay  70602 rows 8.5 MB

Now I'm remodelling this website with just one table:

table all 251.043 rows 64.6 MB

but I don't understand why its now 64.6 MB while it should be 26.5 MB..

Should I go back to my 3 tables? Or is one table the best?

Comment: Where are you getting those sizes from?

Comment: Keep in mind, databases will often allocate space on the heap table when it thinks it might be needed, and not clean it up immediately when rows are deleted.

Comment: @tadman The sizes where from phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally from a logical standpoint you'll want to have similar elements/objects grouped in one table together.  If your three tables had identical fields with a simple flag like 'type' being their only difference then yes, you'll probably want them in the same table (with proper indexing of course).

As Mike Christensen said, the DB will often allocate space when it thinks it might be needed so that could account for the size disparity.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.All 3 tables contain the same fields, so i'm gonna put them all together.